# Incompatible type error when attempting to use variable length argument

Tags: java, variable-length

I am attempting to use a variable length argument in my constructor, however I get the error messages:

1. 'Incompatible types string cannot be converted to int'
2. Illegal start of operation,   ';'  expected

   ```
   public class Personnel {

   private String pname;
   private String rank;
   private String certs [];

   public static int totalPersonnel = 0;

   public Personnel(String name, String rank, String... certs) {

       this.pname = name;
       this.rank = rank;
       this.certs =  certs;

       incrPersonnel();

   }

   public static void incrPersonnel(){
       totalPersonnel++;
   }

   public static void main(String myArgs[]){
       Personnel Alex = new Personnel ("Alex", "CPT", ["none"] );
   ```

   }

   }

Comment: what is this syntax : ` ["none"]`

Comment: Remove the brackets from `["none"]`

Comment: I had meant for it to be an empty placeholder. Thanks, I see the problem now, quite an oversight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to pass an array then the way you are using is not correct instead you have to use `new String[]{"none"}`, so your code should look like this :

```
public static void main(String myArgs[]) {
    Personnel Alex = new Personnel("Alex", "CPT", new String[]{"none"});  
}
```

Or you can also use :

```
public static void main(String myArgs[]) {
    Personnel Alex = new Personnel("Alex", "CPT", "val1", "val2", "val3");
    //--------------------------------------------[_____________________]
}
```

But in your case you pass only one value, so you don't have to use `new String[]{..}`, you need just to pass it like this :

```
Personnel Alex = new Personnel("Alex", "CPT", "none");
```

If you don't want to pass any value, then you don't need to specify it you can just pass the first and second value like :

```
Personnel Alex = new Personnel("Alex", "CPT");
//------------------------------------------^____no need to pass
```

It will return `empty` for the array

Comment: Or just the string as it is varargs

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive explanation, I appreciate it. I did not understand the usage of variable length arguments very well when I posted my question.

Comment: I'm not sure for your last statement, is the array really null? Or is it empty

Comment: oops this is correct @Lino it is empty not null its my bad thank you so much :)